# Oracle JDeveloper install ERROR: Cannot locate the archive

Tags: linux, oracle

I am trying to install Oracle JDeveloper Studio on a CentOS Virtual machine. I have downloaded the install `.bin` and `.zip` files using my user. I then tried to change the owner of the file to `oracle` as this is a requirement for the installation.

I used:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/Downloads
sudo chmod 777 jdev_suite_122140_linux64*
sudo chown oracle:oinstall jdev_suite_122140_linux64*
```

I then used:

```
sudo su oracle
```

As the `oracle` user I then execute:

```
./jdev_suite_122140_linux64.bin
```

but this gives me:

```
ERROR: Cannot locate the archive ./jdev_suite_122140_linux64.bin
```

Does anyone know how I should be doing this?

Comment: what is the result of `ls -l` after you get the error?

Comment: `ls -l` shows both files without issues.